# Python - Can't Build Window With All The Items

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.6

I've tryied to build a Tkinter form in some universal method, but I got a problem.
First look at my Method's code..

```
def BuildWindow(title, args, icon):
    Window = Tk()
    Window.title(title)
    Window.wm_iconbitmap(icon)
    for item in args:
        item.master = Window
        item.pack()
    Window.mainloop()
```

When I'm trying to run this code, I'm getting two differnet Windows: one with the arguments from the list "args", and the other with the title and the icon only.. 
I want all the parameters to appear in the same Form..

can someone help me to solve it?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code presented, I must assume that `args` contains a list of widgets that have already been created. If they've already been created, an instance of `Tk` must already exist. Since this function is also creating in instance of `Tk`, that's why you get two windows.

You must create only a single instance of `Tk` for your entire application.